# PHPMailer : MAIL not accepted from server: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am aware that this has been asked (and answered) often, but the 
solutions are not working for me.
I get this error from last days, and I tried everything :

- I changed the port and the host and the SMTPSecure to (ssl / 465).
- The port is open (587 and 465).
- My php installation has SSL support.
- The php function mail() worked perfectly
- I have the last version of phpmailer
- When i put the smtpAuth , i have an other line error (ERROR: AUTH not
  accepted from server: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.)
- I put my php.ini configuration : 
       SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
       smtp_port = 587
- I also tried (it seems more logical) : SMTP = smtp.myFAI.com
                                        smtp_port = 25

I think it's more a php issue than the code.
Thank you for reading my annoying post ! And if you have any ideas...

```
$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Password='password';
$mail->SetFrom("my_email", 'Me');
$mail->AddAddress("email_to", "");
$mail->From = "my_email";
$mail->FromName= "Me";
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->Subject="Subject";
$mail->Body = "message";
if(!$mail->Send()){echo "not sent";}
else{echo "Sent";}
```

Comment: Have you enabled `extension=php_openssl.dll` in your `php.ini`

Comment: You're missing `$mail->SMTPAuth = true;` to enable auth at all, but it will be much simpler if you just base your code on [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps).

Comment: Hey Synchro. i tried with the smtp auth : $mail->SMTPAuth = true;.     I had another error line : ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.)

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution for my problem . I don't know why it's working, I just add 'ssl://' to the host :

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
```

I had already check this combination (ssl/465), so the solution was adding 'ssl://' to the host.